# Visual Basic Can't Type in Listbox

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Studio and working in a Windows Form Application. I have added a Listbox on my form. The problem I am having is that when I run my application I can't add any text or even select the Listbox to put my cursor in.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, that makes this a vb.net question, not a vba question. Have you tried googling any tutorials about how to add items to a listbox in vb.net? That's what I would recommend.

Comment: If you can't use a `ListBox` properly then either you're doing something wrong or your system is somehow corrupt. You haven't provided us with sufficient information to diagnose either of those situations. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: By the way, you don't add text to a `ListBox` by typing anyway, so if that's what you're expecting then you're wrong from the outset. The control provides a list of items from which you can select one or more. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add values or action to listbox before run it,if you run it without value or action absolutely that will give you nothing.

To add a value in listbox,right click on listbox then select "edit items...".

Or you can make a action like : add text to listbox from textbox,do looping,or another...

Answer (score 0):

From the design window from theToolbox add a TextBox and a Button to your form. (The ListBox is already there, right?) Enter the following code to your form in the code window.

```
'This is the code that runs when the users clicks the button
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'This is the code that copies the text in the text box to the list box
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
        'This code clears the text in the text box
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    End Sub
```

The text in the gray window that appears in light gray and is preceded with an apostrophe are comments; not part of the code. 
Now run the program and type in the text box. Click the button and the text you typed will appear in the list box. Now that you have had this brief introduction to Visual Basic . NET try searching for a beginners tutorial. Come back when you have some code that you wrote but doesn't turn out as you thought.